# request.POST.get() is empty

Tags: django

In views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='lab_3:login',redirect_field_name="next")
def myorders(request): 
    pass
```

I used login_required to redirect to login with parameter "next".

```
class user_login(View):

    def post(self,request):
        from_order = request.POST.get('next','')
        username = request.POST.get('username','')
        password = request.POST.get('password','')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        current_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.localtime(time.time()))

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                request.session['last_login'] = current_time
                request.session.set_expiry(60*60)

                if from_order:
                    order_list = Order.objects.filter(client=user).all()
                    return render(request,'myapp/myorders.html',{
                        'order_list':order_list,
                    })
                return render(request,'myapp/index.html',{
                    'user':user,
                })
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Your account is disabled.')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid login details.')

    def get(self,request):
        from_order = request.GET.get('next', '')
        return render(request, 'myapp/login.html')
```

I used Debug to check the user_login view and I find request.GET.get() can get the parameter from myorders view. But the request.POST.get is always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `login_required` perform simple redirection to login page. It's not perform post request and since doesn't provide any POST data. That's why `request.POST` in your login view is empty after redirection.

It's can add `next` GET argument nevertheless to the login url like this: `/accounts/login/?next=/polls/3/` which you can see using `request.GET` in your `login` view.

To populate `request.POST` with data you should add and submit login form:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Post data">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense